# Weight and Height for a 2 year old girl

Tags: toddler, health, eating

My 2 year niece weighs 30kgs (66.13 lbs) and tall for her age (3 feet/91cm tall). Despite her weight she does not really eat much.. we we're advised that it's growth spurt. Is there a cause for concern? Is this normal?

Comment: what's the unit kls? 30lbs is very normal (http://www.babycenter.com/0_your-childs-size-and-growth-timeline_10357633.bc), while 30klbs will be a bit too heavy

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE! Was it a medical professional that advised this is part of a growth spurt?

Comment: You haven't mentioned height, so there's no way to tell what her weight should be, but if you meant 30kgs, that seems like twice of what even a large 2yo should weigh.

Comment: Growth spurt was advised by her pediatrician.. yes 30kgs..it seems a bit odd to me as her height seems to be of a 4 yr old.

Comment: @Lanie - You still have not mentioned her height. There are many growth charts (this [this](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/set1clinical/cj41c022.pdf) all over the internet, but you need age, weight and _height_. Pick one appropriate for your nationality.

Comment: @Dave- She's 3ft (91.44cm?) Tall..Filipina by heritage..i'll check the chart you provided thanks Dave

Answer (score 1):

For weight, 30 kilograms is quite heavy for a 2 year old.  Per the [cdc growth charts](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/set1clinical/cj41c022.pdf)<sup>1</sup> @dave posted in comments, a two year old will typically be between 10 and 15 kilograms (20-35 pounds) (5%-95% range).  However, you need to take into account her height in determining what you'd expect her to weigh; for that you have weight-for-stature (weight-for-height) charts.

Based on the height you reported (3' or 91cm), the range is slightly higher (as she is indeed tall for her age); the typical range (5%-95%) is [between 12 and 16 kilograms](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/set1clinical/cj41c026.pdf).  30 kilograms is off the linked chart; you'd expect a 30kg child to be more like 4' tall (125cm) or more.

So - no, it's not "normal", based on the statistics.  Whether it's healthy is something the pediatrician would address.  If they're not concerned, then perhaps it's worth asking why?  Perhaps the measurements were provided incorrectly - maybe she's really 30 pounds for example, and her parents misheard/misunderstood the doctor. If she seems substantially heavier than other children her age (30kg would be *substantially* heavier), and it's something that's worrying her parents, it's definitely something worth asking about - if nothing else just to find out why the pediatrician isn't worried.

<sub>[1] CDC growth charts are based on American children; [WHO growth charts](http://www.who.int/childgrowth/standards/Technical_report.pdf?ua=1) may show somewhat different results, although usually in the same ballpark.  Unfortunately they're much harder to read, so we tend to use CDC charts here.  For reference, the weight-for-height for girls in WHO shows slightly higher (5% or so) estimates than the CDC does, but not enough to change the details significantly above.</sub>

Comment: Just a note: you're not interpreting the chart correctly. If she is 95%ile in height at two, her normal weight is *not* what is in the *5th to 95%ile*. Someone in the 95%ile of height should be somewhere in the same vicinity in weight. (Indeed, someone in the 95%ile of height is usually off the chart in weight; but if she were in the 5%ile of weight, I suspect there would be a serious problem to solve.) Nonetheless, one point on the chart doesn't really give as much information as would the points on the first 24 months.

Comment: @anongoodnurse That's what the second paragraph was intended to address - the weight-for-height percentiles should indicate that relationship.  (Technically, the 95th percentile for weight is still 95th percentile for weight regardless of height - so > 95th percentile is still unusual, regardless of the obviously correlated factor of height.)  I edited to make that a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll share this with her parents.. she's now seeing a new pediatrician.thank you everyone for the input